# integral of $xf(x)$ for normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, density-function

from Gregory book i read that

$\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}(\mu + \sigma x)f(x)dx = \mu F(\mu/\sigma) + \sigma 
f(\mu/\sigma)$

where $f(x)$ is the density of a normal distribution and $F(x)$ the cumulative distribution.

Of course I agree with the first term $\mu F(\mu/\sigma)$ coming from the integration of $\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}\mu f(x)dx$. But I'm not sure how the second term (i.e.  $\sigma f(\mu/\sigma)$ is obtained. I thought at integrating by part, but this doesn't seem correct.

Could someone help? Many thanks

Comment: Is $f$ the density of $N(0,\,1)$, $N(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$ or an arbitrary Normal distribution?

Comment: If $f$ is the $N(0,\,1)$ PDF, you just need to work out the antiderivative of $xe^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: @J.G. $f$ is the density of N(0,1).. using integration by part on $x e^{-x^2/2}$?

Comment: The substitution $y=x^2/2$ is easier.

Comment: if you write it as an answer i will close the question

Comment: All right, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution $y=x^2/2$ shows $\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty xf(x)dx=f(-\mu/\sigma)$ (proof is an exercise).

Answer (score 1):

While an answer has already been provided by [J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g), kindly allow me to share also the detailed proof.

Assuming that the value of the asset follows a drift and diffusion process like the following

$$v(z)=\mu+\sigma z, z\sim N(0,1)$$

then, the expected positive exposure (EPE) is derived as follows:

$$E[\max(v(z),0)]=\int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} (\mu+ \sigma z) \underbrace{f(z)}_{\text{pdf of} N(0,1)} \,dz = \underbrace{\mu \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} f(z) \,dz}_{(1)} + \underbrace{\sigma \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} z f(z) \,dz}_{(2)}$$

Component (1):
$$\mu \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} f(z) \,dz = \mu \Big(\underbrace{F(\infty)}_{=1} - F\big(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\big)\Big) = \mu\underbrace {F (\frac{\mu}{\sigma})}_{\text{cdf}}$$

Component (2):
$$\sigma \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} z f(z) \,dz = \sigma \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} z e^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}} \,dz$$

By setting $z^2 = u$ (thus, $\frac{du}{dz} = 2z$), the latter equation takes the following formation:

$$\sigma \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{u}{2}} \,du =\sigma \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \Big[e^{-\frac{z^{2}}{2}} \Big]_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} = \sigma \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})^{2}}}_{f(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})}$$

Combining the final formations of the two components provides:

$$E[\max(v(z),0)] =\mu F (\frac{\mu}{\sigma}) + \sigma f(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}) $$